# How can I determine if the desktop window is visible in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, desktop, window

I have a Conky script that I always update to increase the delay before it starts. The delay has to be at least how long it must wait till the background is displayed otherwise Conky is hidden behind the wallpaper. Bad.

Now that is to happen when I log on. When I am already logged on I would like the script not to wait but start immediately.

My desktop environment is **Xfce 4.12** on **Manjaro 16**. Is there a way to reliably determine when the desktop is ready/visible?

---

**EDIT**: Following [Edgar Gril's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288240/86969), I've updated my script. It reads as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Try to detect screen width to correctly position Conky
# to the right of the first monitor
eval $(xdpyinfo | sed -e '/screen\s\+#0/,+1!d' \
    -e '/screen/d' \
    -e 's@\s\+dimensions:\s\+\([0-9]\+\)x\([0-9]\+\).*@WIDTH=\1; HEIGHT=\2@g') 2>/dev/null \
    || WIDTH=1920

# Wait till the desktop window is ready (more or less)
# Method 1:
#while ! xwininfo -name Bureau 2>&1 > /dev/null; do sleep 1s; done
# Method 2:
while ! xwininfo -tree -root | \
    grep -qE '\("xfdesktop"\s+"\w+"\)\s+'${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}'\+0\+0'; \
do sleep 1s; done

cd $HOME/.conky
exec /usr/bin/conky ${WIDTH:+-x $WIDTH -y 48} "$@"
```

It's saved as `/usr/local/bin/conky.sh` and is typically called as follows from `.config/autostart`:

```
conky.sh -p 2 -q -c ringrc
```

with 2 seconds being not enough in this case.

Comment: That sounds like a bug: the wallpaper should always be placed in the background, even if some windows are already present. What program are you using to display that wallpaper?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a well known "feature" (at least several years ago when I started to use Conky). At that time the only possible workaround was to delay Conky startup, which is the purpose of the `-p` option. I've setup my script to run from `.config/autostart` and it may very well happen that the desktop is not ready before Conky is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that the desktop wallpaper could be a child window created by `xfdesktop`, a lead to follow could be exploring the content of the X windows list with the command:

```
xwininfo -tree -root
```

excerpt of the output ("Scrivania" simply meaning "Desktop" in english):

```
    0x800744 (has no name): ()  4x538+736+30  +755+50
    0x800743 (has no name): ()  4x541+0+30  +19+50
 0x8005f9 (has no name): ()  1920x1080+0+0  +0+0
    16 children:
    0x1400003 "Scrivania": ("xfdesktop" "Xfdesktop")  1920x1080+0+0 +0+0
       1 child:
       0x1400004 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +-1+-1
    0x800608 (has no name): ()  1x1+0+0  +0+0
    0x800607 (has no name): ()  1x1+0+0  +0+0
```

Following this hypothesis it is relatively simple in your script to check if the window belonging to `xfdesktop` exists and/or has children

Comment: Excellent! It's just too bad the window title is translated but on my system there's only one "xfdesktop" window that has a *+0+0* offset, which is the desktop window. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried detecting the background window as planned but it doesn't work: Conky is still appearing on a window that gets hidden by the background shortly after. In fact the *desktop* window is available immediately and the problem of Conky being hidden by the background (I guess) is not about detecting when the desktop window is available. Maybe I'm trying to detect the wrong window or maybe the only solution is to use the start delay.

Comment: Could you please post on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) both your script and the output of `xwininfo -tree -root`, taken after Conky is hidden?

Comment: I've updated my question with the script; it's not too big. As for the log, well, I have to log off and on again, which I tend to do not-so-often given the time it takes to prepare my desktop for daily usage. Will do when I can.